# May I please have a mod remove the Community Wiki status from my post?

Tags: support, status-completed, faq

I asked this in chat:

> As of right now, I've gotten 9 upvotes today for the following:
>
> [Why do credit card forms ask for Visa, MasterCard, etc.?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51346/why-do-credit-card-forms-ask-for-visa-mastercard-etc/51349#51349)
>
> Why am I not getting credit? I have 0 reputation for today. I maxed out yesterday, but today nothing and I'm getting votes. What gives?

@BenBrocka replied with:

> @CodeMaverick The post was made "community Wiki" due to the high number of edits
>
> [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

The link @BenBrocka listed states:

> ## How can the Community Wiki status be removed from a post?
>
> [Moderators can remove it, when necessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373). Once removed, the post will never be given the CW status automatically *due to a high number of edits* again.

In instances where the Community Wiki status is caused by owner edits, I feel that goes against the whole idea of editing and improving your own post.  The owner should get the credit (reputation) they deserve for their post.  For my pown post, I worked very hard to keep it up-to-date with new information, corrections, and modifications based on discussions that were/are in the comments.

It seems I'm not alone in this thinking.  Here are some comments from the *Moderators can remove it, when necessary* link quoted above:

> **43 votes as of now**
>
> Force community wiki on owner edits is absolutely horrible. It should die a swift death. The only reason it exists is to prevent gaming by bumping, and that's a wretched excuse to so strongly discourage edits and improvements by the original author. The problem is gaming - fixing it by penalizing edits and improvements is just insane. Didn't anyone ask themselves why edits need to bump posts at all? Why not just fix that broken behaviour rather than cripple one of the most useful tools (edit and improve) of SE sites? –  J

---

> **13 votes of now**
>
> @J... I wish I could upvote your comment a million times. –  That Brazilian Guy

---

> **3 votes of now**
>
> @J... I wish I could frame your comment and hang it on every wall of the SE offices. –  Django Reinhardt

Comment: I've just checked and it's now been reverted back to a standard post for you.

Comment: Yea, I was just about to delete this. Should I?

Comment: No, it's a useful post for future people who have the same situation.